# Does reportlab's renderPM work on Google appengine?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, reportlab

I wanted to use ReportLab's RenderPM to generate images on Google App-Engine but it looks like it depends on c libraries. Does anyone know if it's possible to get it working?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question - as indicated by Wooble, reportlab itself works fine on Appengine (being pure python) but the RenderPM library doesn't.